# GOTO/OF in HP Time-Shared BASIC

Tags: goto, basic

For the following code in HP Time-Shared BASIC, I am wondering about line 2270:

```
2180  INPUT X
2190  IF X=1 THEN 2210
2200  LET X=2
2210  LET X=X+1
2220  IF X=3 THEN 2260
2230  IF B>39 THEN 2260
[irrelevant code lines removed for clarity]
2260  X1=X1*(-1)
2270  GOTO X OF 2290,2540,2720
```

Based on other examples in this code base, it seems GOTO [variable] OF [line1,line2,...] seems to be the equivalent of if X == 1 GOTO LINE 1; if X == 2, GOTO LINE 2, etc.

I found the relevant Wikipedia bit "Calculated flow-control via the GOTO/OF and GOSUB/OF statements" but I'd like more clarity.

Can anyone confirm?

Thanks,

Caleb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thankfully, the Wikipedia page has a link to all the original documentation:

http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/hp/2000TSB/

This includes a full language reference:

http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/hp/2000TSB/22687-90001_AccessBasic9-75.pdf

Which says this about GOTO/OF on page 11-40

> **GO TO *numeric expression* OF *statement number list***
>
> ...
>
> When the second form of the GO TO statement is used, the *numeric expression* is evaluated and rounded to an integer "n". Control then is transferred to the "nth" *statement number* in the ***statement number list***, where ***statement number list*** is one or more *statement numbers* separated by commas. If there is no *statement number* corresponding to the value of the *numeric expression*, the GO TO statement is ignored and the statement following the GO TO statement is executed

That appears to confirm your guess